# Where can I find documentation for Umbraco 6?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6

I have recently taken over maintenance of some legacy client projects built with Umbraco 6. I have extensive ASP.NET experience but very little with any version of Umbraco. Unfortunately it seems all relevant documentation has been deleted from our.umbraco.com and any links I've been able to find so far that specifically refer to v6 in the URL, are being silently redirected to v7 docs. This is not at all helpful. An Amazon search only revealed one book published specifically on Umbraco, which dates back to 2011 and doesn't specify which version it covers.

Can anyone tell me if there are any comprehensive API documents or even introductory guides on how to use or develop against this particular version?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I suggest you ask them or the community linked from their site. And perhaps the 7 docs are not that much different from v6

Answer (score 0):

Sadly most of the documentation from prior to V7 is either gone or has been redirected to the newer documentation (as you've discovered).

There are probably quite a few older blog posts etc still floating around for the older versions, but I don't know about official content.

The internet archive doesn't appear to have cached any older versions of the documentation sadly. The book that you found will be the one that covers V4, so while it might help a bit, a lot changed in V6 (the introduction of MVC and Razor templates for example).

Some of the V7 docs are still sort of relevant to V6 (specifically the templating stuff and some of the APIs), the main difference is that prior to V7 the back office was entirely web forms, whereas from 7 onwards it was a mix of angular and webforms, before becoming all Angular later on.